# Acrescentar tags HTML quando aparecer um caractere A-Z javascript

Tags: javascript, html

Tenho uma string com o seguinte formato:

```
let texto = "Dub. - 16h00A, 19h00A, 22h00A"
```

Gostaria de fazer colocar as tags **sup** e **b** entre as letras A. Por exemplo:

```
let new_texto = "Dub. - 16h00<sup><b>A</b></sup>, 19h00<sup><b>A</b></sup>, 22h00<sup><b>A</b></sup>"
```

A primeira string é resultado de uma query de banco e existem outras strings neste mesmo formato, porém além do caractere A, podem surgir outros caracteres como B,C,D, etc. Gostaria de fazer uma função para verificar a ocorrência da letra na string e colocar as tags entre esta letra.

Outro exemplo:

```
let texto2 = Leg. - 18h10D, 18h20C, 21h40D, 22h00C
```

Como seria:

```
let new_texto2 = Leg. - 18h10<sup><b>D</b></sup>, 18h20<sup><b>C</b></sup>, 21h40<sup><b>D</b></sup>, 22h00<sup><b>C</b></sup>
```

O que consegui fazer é fazer a substituição por uma string fixa e não dinâmica de acordo com a letra que aparece. Meu código de teste é esse:

```
let texto = "Dub. - 16h00A, 19h00A, 22h00A";
    let regex = /[A-Z]/g; // regex de todas as letras do alfabeto maiusculas
    let legenda = texto.substring(texto.indexOf('-') , 0); // pega o tipo de legenda do filme  
    let substitui = texto.substring(6).replace(regex, '<sup><b>A</b></sup>'); // substitui as ocorrências das letras
    console.log(legenda + '-' + substitui);
```

Comment: Em vez de substring, vc pode substituir somente se a letra estiver depois de "dois números, letra h, dois números", algo assim: https://ideone.com/XYeoAL

Answer (score -3, accepted):

```
let texto = "Dub. - 16h00A, 19h00A, 22h00A";
let regex = /[A-Z]/g

texto = texto.substring(6).replace(regex, "<sup><b>$&</b></sup>");
```

Testa isso.

Comment: Melhorou bastante mas ainda o D do Dub está sendo substituído. *<sup><b>D</b></sup>ub. -*

Comment: @Sr.Caveira Deu certo, obrigado. Apenas tinha que substituir nesta linha: let substitui = texto.substring(6).replace(regex, '<sup><b>$&</b></sup>').